# Unable to find the error in code for mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created one stored procedure in which every thing is written according 
code

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mark_all_read`(IN user_name VARCHAR(50),IN group_name VARCHAR(50),IN choice CHAR(10),IN nid CHAR(30))
BEGIN
IF choice = 'all' THEN
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name;
ELSE
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name AND noticationId = nid;
END IF; 
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Error : 
[image]

Comment: are you creating this procedure in new empty tab?? Then don't. To create a procedure right click on stored procedure >create stored procedure>then paste your code there  without 'DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you .. this screenshot is of query which was fired using SQLyog

Comment: but i created another procedure using the same thing in which IF condition was not there and it was working with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) check the first statement `DELIMITER $$;`, it should [just] be `DELIMITER $$` with no semi-colon

2.) check the last statement `DELIMITER;`, it should be `DELIMITER ;` with space in between

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mark_all_read`(IN user_name VARCHAR(50),IN group_name VARCHAR(50),IN choice CHAR(10),IN nid CHAR(30))
BEGIN
IF choice = 'all' THEN
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name;
ELSE
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name AND noticationId = nid;
END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Explanation:

1.) `DELIMITER $$;` means you are modifying the default delimiter from `;` to `$$;`. However, at the end of your code, the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement was terminated by `$$` (instead of `$$;`), which MySQL does not recognize. To make the solution simple, I used `$$` and end the `CREATE PROCEDURE` with `$$`. You need to modify the delimiter because there are semi-colon `;` delimiters within your procedure, else MySQL would not know which delimiter terminates the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

2.) `DELIMITER;` (without space separator) means you are terminating the `DELIMITER` statement just like `SELECT * FROM TABLE;` and not changing the terminator from `$$` back to `;` It is also syntactically incorrect. `DELIMITER ;` (with space separator) simply changes the delimiter back to `;`. Why? For one, your codes within your procedures are terminated by `;`. MySQL would not be able to terminate the procedure statements on run-time if you forgot to do `DELIMITER ;` - you will get errors if you execute/call the procedure afterwards.

You may further read MySQL documentation regarding the matter. Hope explanation helps.

Comment: It works.. wants to know why this semi colon spacing matters?

Comment: @ShubhamNigam, I added "explanation" above. Hopefully it would help you understand the matter.

Comment: ya thanks your explanation is quite helpful.. Keep Helping others.. :)

Answer (score 0):

its working

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `mark_all_read`(IN user_name VARCHAR(50),IN group_name VARCHAR(50),IN choice CHAR(10),IN nid CHAR(30))
BEGIN
IF choice = 'all' THEN
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name;
ELSE
 UPDATE notifications SET STATUS = 'read' WHERE USER = user_name AND groupId = group_name AND noticationId = nid;
END IF; 
END $$
```

Comment: so what is the issue with DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`